# Vnet Storage account container returns AuthorizationFailure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, vnet

Unable to upload the file using Azure app service(Same Network Security Group) in Azure Storage account container returns below Error

> Status: 403   ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure  Error Message: This
> request is not authorized to perform this operation

Created Virtual network as vnet-network and create 3 subnets

- app-subnet: 10.0.1.0/24
- upload-subnet: 10.0.5.0/24
- db-subnet:  10.0.3.0/24

Created the network security group for above subnets(netowrk_nsg).

Then based on the subnets create App service, private database and storage accounts.

Once it's done created the inbound and outbound security rules

Inbound
[image]

Outbound
[image]

Vnet Configuration
[image]

Storage account Vnet Configuration tab
[image]

App service Vnet Configuration
[image]

Able to connect the App service to database, but unable to connect the app service to storage accounts.

Which one not allowing to storage account, Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

App Service wouldn't be using subnet to talk to your storage account by default. If NSG was blocking communications between App Service and Storage Account - you'd get a timeout.
This looks like you storage key is wrong or your SAS token expired

Comment: We are using Private container, if enable public network able to connect storage account without any issues.

Comment: either way its not NSG blocking connections (you'd get a timeout). Did you configure Vnet Integration on the App Service? Did you enable traffic filtering on Storage Account? If so - how did you configure it?

Comment: Please check Storage account Vnet Configuration tab above in question, in the tab itself select created subnet

Comment: the screenshot cuts off, did you allow the vnet\subnet of the app service to access it?

Comment: Yes in the storage account able to select Vnet subnet only, Please check above inbound and outbound rule for network security group. Already allowed in the NSG rules.

Comment: nsg has nothing to do with this, inter vnet communications are allowed by default on the nsg. did you enable vnet integration on the app service?

Comment: Yes Enabled App service and database also. Able to connect App --> database, but unable to connect app--> storage account

Comment: on the screenshot it says `10.0.5.0/24`, but in your question app subnet is `10.0.1.0/24`

Comment: For questioning purpose used like this, actual subnet is 10.0.5.0/24

Comment: can you share vnet integration configuration?

Comment: Please check above

Comment: according to your screenshots you should allow `10.0.1.0/24` subnet, not `10.0.5.0/24` subnet in your storage networking config, can you try that?

Comment: 10.0.1.0/24--> app service , 10.0.5.0/24--> Blob storage both are in same NSG and virtual network suppose to allow inbound and outbound according to security rules.

Comment: disregard nsg, storage account does not allow `10.0.1.0/24` to talk to it, it only allows `10.0.5.0/24` to talk to. fix storage to allow `10.0.1.0/24` to talk to it and it should work

Comment: Allowed both 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.5.0/24, Still face the same issue

Comment: it should definitely work if you configured it like that and vnet integration is configured as on the screenshot. if it doesnt - you need to enable diagnostic logs on the storage account and check which ip is accessing the storage account, it should be something like `10.0.1.5` - if its a public ip of the app service instead - you need to figure out why app service is misconfigured. alternatively you can configure private endpoints on the storage account. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/app-service-to-storage-account-connection-condition-summary/ba-p/2968642 - 3 or 4